# Structure Won't Appear in Control Panel Anymore

Tags: control-panel, structure, database, plugin

Made a rookie mistake and deleted Structure from the server before uninstalling it first from the EE CP. Now, after I've reuploaded it, it still won't appear. I've tried going into the config file and turning off extensions while I reinstall it, no luck. Figuring that this error on my part probably caused some Structure tables to be leftover on the database, I logged into the database and deleted all of the prefixes that matched Structure. Still, no luck.

In short, I'm guessing this is a consequence of my error. If so, how would I go about correcting it? I have too much additional unrelated work on this site to do a backup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you also remove any rows referencing Structure references in the modules, extensions, and accessories tables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, I've gone all throughout the db and can't find any remnants of Structure tables or rows. Are you familiar with what prefixes they use? Guessing it all starts with "exp?" I don't think I missed anything, but could be wrong. 

Thanks!

Comment: You need to look at the rows stored in exp_modules, exp_extensions, exp_accessories, and there may be a row in the exp_actions table as well. Remove those rows.  There may also be some data stored in the site_pages column in the exp_sites table.

Comment: Hey @Solspace - Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I've checked all those tables and rows. Nothing... Frustrating!!!